# CSRF Clarification

Tags: csrf

I'm trying to determine whether the following can be classified as a CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) vulnerability on a website:

If website-1.com contains the following code: `<img src = "http://website-2.com/img.png"></img>`  and "http://website-2.com/img.png" performs a 302 redirect to some sensitive content on website-1.com, such as `http://website-1.com/delete.php?file=test.jpg` and "test.jpg" is deleted succesfully, is that a CSRF attack, even though the malicious content was embedded on website-1.com and not on a 3rd party site?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Deleting with a simple GET request is a pretty bad practice and makes CSRF attacks easy.

Does plain link from website-2 to `http://website-1.com/delete.php?file=test.jpg` cause file to be deleted? If not, then there must be some sort of CSRF protection. But there are a lot of other things to be watched for to ensure CSRF is not possible (like if/how CSRF token is exactly implemented or what sort of user content sites allow, how much admins of both sites trust each other, etc). From your limited info, I'd consider website-1 vulnerable.